# HDMI problem with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, osmc

I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 model B starter kit with an hdmi cable inside. I wanted to create a smart tv using my LG full hd (I don't remember the model).
The problem is that when I use OSMC or LibreELEC the tv starts making strange sounds, even if the sound is 0.  It is like an humming.

If I take off hdmi cable the sounds disappear.

Today, for the first time, the same problem occured while using raspbian.
I tried changing cable and hdmi port on the tv.  My decoder uses hdmi port 3 (of 4) without problems.
Have you a solution?